# AWS RDS gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-rds

I am facing the following issue while connecting to AWS RDS.

I have tried changing the maven dependencies(from 1.11.458 and above) but I'm still facing the same issue while creating `AWSRdsClient`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.<init>(AmazonRDSClient.java:334)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.<init>(AmazonRDSClient.java:318)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClientBuilder.build(AmazonRDSClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClientBuilder.build(AmazonRDSClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.cloudlytics.war.rules.RDS.main(RDS.java:35)
```

Comment: This method was added in the past year. My guess is that your runtime environment is using an old JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
From https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java

Add this to the dependencyManagement section of your POM:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.549</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then use the SDK Maven modules without specifying a version:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```